# Why does FTP client connect to XAMPP/ProFTPD but fails to login with system login details?

Tags: macos, ftp, xampp, proftpd

I am using XAMPP to test out my wordpress site development. I am trying to install a plugin. This requires to send a file over FTP. I am using XAMPP stack which comes with "ProFTPD". So as per the instructions I created a new group called "ftp" and then added my account to this group. Then I set the permissions on the `htdocs` folder as per following commands:

```
sudo chown root:ftp htdocs
sudo chgrp 755 htdocs
```

Now, I start the "ProFTPD" server. I then use Filezilla client to connect to this server using
127.0.0.1
my MAC system user name
my MAC system user password
port 21
Quickconnect.

I get the following error:

```
Status:         Connecting to 127.0.0.1:21...
Status:         Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status:         Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Command:    USER fathemancre
Response:   331 Password required for <my_mac_username>
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   530 Login incorrect.
```

Note that it seems to connect to the FTP server, but why is it unable to login? I am very sure that the password is my system password. What might I be missing in my setup that does not allow my login to the ProFTPD server to be recognized?

XAMPP Details:
Version 5.5.30

MAC OS:
El Capitan 10.11.6
Mac Book Air

Filezilla:
3.21.0

Comment: What does the ProFTPD [debug logging](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Debugging.html) show, when you attempt to login?

Comment: Hello @Castaglia, When I click on ProFTPD, the configure button is greyed out so I am unable to access the error log. Can I view the error log from command line?

Comment: I did not see that you had provided a link with more info. Let me review that and see if I can view the log file.